# Loading files from classpath and .jar

Tags: java, jar, file-read

I make a Spring Boot web application, and I have to read static (.json) files on startup.

No problem, it works when I start the app in Idea. But if I run mvn package, and start I start the jar, the given path (BASE_DIR) does not exists anymore, so the files cannot be found.

**How can I solve to read the files starting with Idea and the .jar as well?**

```
package skyxplore.dataaccess.gamedata.base;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import skyxplore.dataaccess.gamedata.entity.abstractentity.GeneralDescription;

@Slf4j
public abstract class AbstractGameDataService<V> extends HashMap<String, V> {
    public static final String BASE_DIR = "src/main/resources/data/gamedata/";

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final JsonFileFilter jsonFilter = new JsonFileFilter();

    private final String source;

    public AbstractGameDataService(String source) {
        this.source = BASE_DIR + source;
    }

    protected void loadFiles(Class<V> clazz) {
        File root = new File(source);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Source directory does not exists. Path: " + root.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if (!root.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source must be a directory. Path: " + root.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        File[] files = root.listFiles(jsonFilter);
        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                String key = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
                V content = objectMapper.readValue(file, clazz);
                if (content instanceof GeneralDescription) {
                    GeneralDescription d = (GeneralDescription) content;
                    log.info("Loaded element. Key: {}, Value: {}", key, content);
                    put(d.getId(), content);
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException(source + " cannot be loaded. Unknown data type.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void init();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After you package your applications, resource files are no longer accessible from file system - thus you cannot list/open them using `File`. You need to read them as resources from JAR using `class.readResourceAsStream` for example. When you run it from IntelliJ files are not read from JAR but from project directory.

Here you have [Oracles Java tutorial on how to use resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)

Another solution (as you have some additional logic for reading files) you could put files aside JAR not as resource and read it from there then.

Comment: class.getResourceAsStream returns stream of one specified file. But I have to scan one specified folder, and read all files one by one.

Comment: I know, that is problem you have to overcome. Google on how to list resources.

Answer (score -1):

```
BASE_DIR = "src/main/resources/data/gamedata/"
```

Once you do a mvn package, `src/main/resources` folder becomes the root of the jar. You can use a class-loader to load this file. Something like:

```
AbstractGameDataService.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/gamedata/<your json file>")
```

Other possibility since you are using spring-boot, you can leverage spring scanning itself. Using spring constructs load file using : `classpath:/data/gamedata/<your json file>`